# How to delete all data from Redis using RedisTemplate in java

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Lettuce as Redis client for my Java Spring project. I am doing several operations with RedisTemplate. I'm not able to delete all data from Redis using RedisTemplate.

I tried

```
redisTemplate.delete("*")
```

However, this is not making any change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().flushAll();
```

Comment: it is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using kotlin and reactive connection within a suspendable function, the code is:

```
suspend fun flushCache(): String {
   return redisTemplate.connectionFactory.reactiveConnection.serverCommands().flushDb().awaitSingle()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().flushAll();`

This thing is also deprecated.

You can try this one:

```
RedisConnection redisConnection = this.redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection();

RedisSerializer<String> redisSerializer = this.redisTemplate.getKeySerializer();

DefaultStringRedisConnection defaultStringRedisConnection = new DefaultStringRedisConnection(redisConnection, redisSerializer);

defaultStringRedisConnection.flushAll();
```